# Linux - Find files that do not contain certain characters

Tags: linux

I understand that using something like `[^a]*` will output all the files that do not start with `"a"`.

If I want to **echo** files that contain at least 5 characters that do not start with `"abc"` (but can contain `"abc"` in the middle of the filename), how should I go about doing so?

I have

```
 echo [^abc]?????*
```

but the output also removes files like `"123abc"`, which I don't quite understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo for editing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439864/echo-for-editing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't indicate which OS your question applies to, but one way to determine the set of matching files on Mac OS X or Linux would be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "?????*" | egrep -v "./abc"
```

Note that this will list only files in the current directory. If you want to include files in subdirectories, you'll need to remove the *maxdepth* argument.

Also note that these commands are case-sensitive. You'll need to use *-iname* and *-i* to make them case-insensitive.

EDIT:

If you really need to use the *echo* command, the following will work:

```
echo `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "?????*" | egrep -v "./abc"`
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing with just echo? I'm on Linux Mint

Comment: `[^abc]` specifies a single character which cannot be `a`, `b`, or `c`. Glob patterns do not easily bend to what you ask for, you have to use a more powerful formalism, such as the `extglob` facility of Bash, or enumerate all the possible cases (`[^a]*`, `a[^b]*`, `a`, `ab[^c]*`, `ab`, or in your particular case, even more complex).

Comment: I don't understand the importance of using the *echo* command to solve the problem. *echo* directs output to the screen as does *find*.

That said, I've edited my answer.