# Complex shell wildcard

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, echo

I want to use echo to display(not content) directories that start with atleast 2 characters but can't begin with "an"

For example if had the following in the directory:
`a as an23 an23 blue`

I would only get 
`as blue` back

I tried `echo ^an*` but that returns the directory with 1 charcter too.

Is there any way i can do this in the form of `echo globalpattern`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shells extended globbing feature, in bash:

```
bash$ setsh -s extglob
bash$ echo !(@(?|an*))
```

The `!()` construct inverts its internal expression, see [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) for more.

In zsh:

```
zsh$ setopt extendedglob
zsh$ print *~(?|an*)
```

In this case the `~` negates the pattern before the tilde. See the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want at least two characters in the names, you can use `printf '%s\n' ??*` to echo each such name on a separate line.  You can then eliminate those names that start with `an` with `grep -v '^an'`, leading to:

```
printf '%s\n' ??* | grep -v '^an'
```

The quotes aren't strictly necessary in the `grep` command with modern shells.  Once upon a quarter of a century or so ago, the Bourne shell had `^` as a synonym for `|` so I still use quotes around carets.

If you absolutely must use `echo` instead of `printf`, then you'll have to map white space to newlines (assuming you don't have any names that contain white space).

---

> I'm trying with just the echo command, no grep either?

What about:

```
echo [!a]?* a[!n]*
```

The first term lists all the two-plus character names not beginning with `a`; the second lists all the two-plus character names where the first is `a` and the second is not `n`.

Comment: I'm trying with just the echo command, no grep either? ... any way i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but you'd likely be better off with ls or even find:

```
echo * | tr ' ' '\012' | egrep '..' | egrep -v '^an'
```

Shell globbing is a form of regex, but it's not as powerful as egrep regex's.

Comment: You can collapse the two into `egrep -v '^(.$|an)'`

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think ordinary shell globbing meets the criteria for regular expressions.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without piping, but just using echo ?

Comment: Plain `grep` is sufficient for both `'..'` and `'^an'` -- but you need egrep for alternation (`|`). @triplee: Clever, your `egrep` regexp would match an empty line, but you'll never get an empty string as a file name.

Comment: @Beginnernato: See Thor's answer (but think about the tradeoff between efficiency  and clarity; I'd have to RTFM to figure out what `echo !(@(?|an*))` does).

Comment: hmm I'm trying to avoid bash and the '(' brackets ... just using basic patterning